# Is there a way to distinguish `{x?: boolean}` and `{x: boolean|undefined}`?

Tags: typescript

This works for both `aGood` and `aBad`:

```
type AOptional = {x?: boolean};
const aBad: AOptional = { x: undefined };
const aGood: AOptional = { };
```

I don't want it to work. I want only `aGood` to pass type check. 
Is there way to define `AOptional` in a way that would enforce that?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think we can do it for a variable .. we might concoct something for a function parameter... but I am curios why you want to forbit one but allow the other ..

Comment: It's more of a principle question - I thought there should be a way to distinguish:
`{x?: boolean}` and `{x: boolean|undefined}`, but there isn't

Comment: You can distinguish them, `{ x: boolean | undefined }` is assignable to `{ x?: boolean }` but not the other way around. But the object literal with type `{ x: undefined }` will be assignable to `{x?: boolean}`.

Comment: ok, yeah. That's a good point. You can copy the comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can distinguish between `{ x: boolean | undefined }` and `{ x?: boolean }`. `{ x: boolean | undefined }` is assignable to `{ x?: boolean }` but not the other way around.

But the object literal with type `{ x: undefined }` will be assignable to `{x?: boolean }` under any compiler settings.